# How to sort by order in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the first array that be like

```
status = [
{title: 'pending', order: 1},
{title: 'success', order: 2}
]
```

And I have the second array that be like

```
task = [
{status: 'success', price: 100},
{status: 'success', price: 150},
{status: 'pending', price: 100}, 
{status: 'success', price: 300}
]
```

How Can I sort This for results be like

```
task = [
{status: 'pending', price: 100},
{status: 'success', price: 100},
{status: 'success', price: 150},
{status: 'success', price: 300}
]
```

sort by order of status from the first array

Comment: what have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and by passing the comparator function to `sort` method

```js
const status = [
  { title: "pending", order: 1 },
  { title: "success", order: 2 },
];

const task = [
  { status: "success", price: 100 },
  { status: "success", price: 150 },
  { status: "pending", price: 100 },
  { status: "success", price: 300 },
];

const dict = new Map(status.map(o => [o.title, o.order]));
const result = [...task].sort((a, b) => dict.get(a.status) - dict.get(b.status));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: nice and elegant. I think the sort should also be sorting by price within the status group.

Comment: @DovRine OP mentioned specifically *sort by order of status from the first array*.

Comment: Yes, but the example output shows it sorted on price as well

Comment: Output also show it sorted by the `order` as well...

Comment: OP also mentioned: "How Can I sort This for results be like"

Comment: you are correct. well done.

Comment: It looks like a coincidence, though

Comment: @DovRine the input was already ordered by price. [`Array.prototype.sort()` preserves relative ordering when the callback returns `0` for two elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability). tl;dr it's not a coincidence that the order of the price is still correct.